# svn client on windows stuck every time I get asked a single letter prompt. How to make it work?

Tags: windows, svn

Every time the svn client asks me a question to be answered with a single letter, the application gets stuck. The only way to get back to a PS prompt is to kill svn from the task manager.

```
PS> svn commit

Log message unchanged or not specified
(a)bort, (c)ontinue, (e)dit:
q
```

What is the reason and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, svn commit is expecting a log message. The easy solution is to supply one via the `-m` option. For example:

```
svn commit -m "Change never changes"
```

It crashes because if the editor is not set, the shell will not return control to the user.

**References**

- [Using External Editors - SVN Book - VisualSVN Help Center](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/externaleditors/)
- [4. Setting Up Version Control Using Subversion - Java Power Tools [Book]](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-power-tools/9780596527938/ch04.html)